# Angular - Cannot find name CookieService

Tags: javascript, angular, cookies, angular-services, angular-template

I've installed ngx cookie in my angular project, but unfortunatelly It's not recognized in my app.. I don't know what to do..

I saw in my node_modules folder ngx-cookie is there, but somehow it's not recognized in my app..

Here is my node_module:

[image]

It's also in my package.json

[image]

I worked with ngx-cookie before and I never had any issue, I simply used commands like this (In case I want specific version):

```
npm install ngx-cookie@2.0.1
```

And to latest version I used this command:

```
npm i ngx-cookie
```

But when I try to use it in my project it gaves me an error:

[image]

Any kind of help would be awesome

Thanks guys

Cheers!

Comment: Try to add an import statement in the file you are using this service.

Comment: Did you import the module in your module.ts?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie#installation

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `CookieService` in your module with `CookieModule.forRoot()` and as an import at the top of the page using `import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie';`